# Get the Name on the Current Page form the params in Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

How can i get the name of the current page in the params in nuxt3?

I am using nested routes

My Structure is like this

```
Pages
    |--index.vue    
    |--dashboard.vue
    |--dashboard/
               |--index.vue
               |--alert.vue
               |--messages.vue
```

I can vist the alert page with `http://localhost/dashboard/alert`

I want to grap the name of alert page in the params and print it on the alert page

I tried the useRoute composable  `useRoute()` but there is no method to get the page name from the params

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, and based on the URL structured, there are no `params`.

If you want to grab the name of the page like this.

**Method 1**

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
defineOptions({
    name: 'Alert'
})
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        {{ $router.currentRoute.value!.matched[0]['components']!.default['name'] }}
    </div>
</template>
```

**Edit:**

**Method 2**

If the `defineOptions` is a bit complex, you can do it like this.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const pageName = useRouter().currentRoute.value!.matched[0]['components']!.default['__name']
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        {{ pageName }}
    </div>
</template>
```

**Note:** This will throw a typescript error. But, it will still display the page name.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> '"__name"' can't be used to index type 'RouteComponent'.   Property
> '__name' does not exist on type 'RouteComponent'.

To fix that, you can make assertion like this and that will fix the issue.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const pageName = (useRouter().currentRoute.value!.matched[0]['components']!.default as { __name: string })['__name']
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        {{ pageName }}
    </div>
</template>
```

**Method 3 - Reusable on every page**

`~/composables/get-page-name.ts`

```js
import { RouteRecordName } from 'vue-router'
export default function getPageName(routeName: RouteRecordName | null | undefined) {
    if (routeName) {
        const words = routeName.toString().split('-')
        return words[words.length - 1] === 'index' ? 'home' : words[words.length - 1]
    }
}
```

**routeName**

The `routeName` parameter will output the unique route identifier. For the nested routes, it will output a kebab case string. A combination of parent route and child route `parent-child`. E.g. On your Alert page, the output will be `dashboard-alert`.

**getPageName**

We are checking if there is a `routeName`, and if the routeName exists, we convert it to a string and then split it into an array of words using '-' as the separator. Lastly, we check if the last word in the array is 'index'. if it is, we return 'home'. Otherwise, we return the last word in the array.

Usage on the page.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        {{ getPageName($route.name) }}
    </div>
</template>
```

`$route.name` will display the unique identifier of the route.

Comment: i can't understand your solution

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. My understanding with your question is you want to get the page name right? The structured pages based on your question does not have any params.

Comment: thanks for the answer. yes the current page does not have a params. The ```useRoute().path ```composable gives access to a path method. However the it gives the full path. Your above code is to complex for me . I defineOptions({
    name: 'Alert'
})tried it but it did not work

Comment: I've edited my answer. I added an alternative,  and yeah, I wish there is a simpler or cleaner way to achieve it.

Comment: @foliwe83, may I ask what's is not working for you? I've created an example here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-rjroz7?file=pages%2Fdashboard%2Falert.vue

Comment: Thanks very much @ReaganM . Method 3 worked. Though i don't really understand what is going on.

Comment: My pleasure! I've added an explanation hope that will help you.